# How to fix "My Nextcloud login pages stays empty"

Tags: cloudflare, nextcloud

I had this issue a few days back, where the Nextcloud login page just stayed empty. I use Nextcloud behind Cloudflare.[image: Empty Nextcloud login page]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by turning off Cloudflare's Rocket Loader. In order to do that go to Settings -> Speed -> Optimizing and then turn off Rocket Loader™.

Comment: That worked! To make this issue easier to find, here's the console error to make it easier to search for: 
Refused to load … /cdn-cgi/scripts/7d0fa10a/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.